# Javascript New Function - Best way to pass large number of functions as parameter

Tags: javascript, angular, eval

In angular project and learning to build a feature to run a custom script using the new function method. With the great help from this forum I have been able to come up with core script solution.

The question I have if I have a large number of custom functions I need to pass into New Function to access what would be the best method?

So far I have 2 options:

Option 1.
Passing each function as parameter. My concern if there is 50 plus function this could look messy.

eg

```
const userFunction = new Function('testFunc1','testFunc2','testFunc3'...'testFunc50', script);
```

Option 2.
Nest the functions in parent function. The draw back is to access the function we need to call the parent function which again can look messy in the code writing. Eg

parentFunc().nestFunc().

**Question is there a better way to do this?**

Code and stackblitz below.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bx5kia?file=src/main.ts

```
option1() {
    var nestFunc1 = () => {
      alert('Nest1');
    };
    var nestFunc2 = () => {
      alert('Nest2');
    };
    const script = `
    var value = 1 +4;\n
    console.log('value',value);\n
    nestFunc1();\n
    console.log("End Script");\n
  `;

    const userFunction = new Function('nestFunc1', 'nestFunc2', script);
    userFunction(nestFunc1, nestFunc2);
  }
  option2() {
    const script = `
    var value = 1 +4;\n
    console.log('value',value);\n
    parentFunc().nestFunc2();\n
    console.log("End Script");\n
  `;

    var parentFunc = (msg?: string) => {
      console.log('Test Function', msg);
      var nestFunc1 = () => {
        alert('Nest 1');
      };
      var nestFunc2 = () => {
        alert('Nest 2');
      };
      return { nestFunc1, nestFunc2 };
    };

    const userFunction = new Function('parentFunc', script);
    userFunction(parentFunc);
  }
```

Comment: Put the functions in an array, then you need only one parameter.

Comment: option 2 seems to be the better idea among the two. To add on to the answer provided by @NoNam4, you can make `userFunction` as a higher order function that receives the `parentFunction` and optionally destructure it in the signature `userFunction = ({ nestFunct1, nestFunc2 })`

Comment: Thanks for your comment not sure how to put the nestFunc2 into a signature and calling it, I get unfdefined.  How do I make uesrFunction as a higher order function of parent? My very poor attempt it here. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wwc7pn?file=src/main.ts

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not an expert with Angular but as we are working with JS maybe I can give you some light in plain JS and then you can convert it to Angular syntax.

In JS you can write functions inside an array:

```
const functions = [
    () => console.log( 'Nest 1' ),
    () => console.log( 'Nest 2' )
]
```

And then, in your `userFunction` you can make a loop inside this array calling all functions:

```
const userFunction = ( functionsArray ) => {
    functionsArray.forEach( nestedFunction => nestedFunction() )
}
```

Hope I can give you any idea :)

Comment: Thanks I am struggling to put this into practice. I still need to call the script to be executed so not sure how could work in the example provided.